# How do you deal with questions that answer themselves in the question?

Tags: discussion

In [How are you preparing for the possible dollar (USD) collapse?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/how-are-you-preparing-for-the-possible-dollar-usd-collapse) the asker provides a significant answer to his question in the body of the question.  Is it appropriate to edit that out?  Should we encourage or discourage this behavior.

**Pros:**
 - It shows people are invested in their question and gets them fresh answers

**Cons:**
 - It doesn't always leave much room for answers.
 - It sometimes verges on a "blog post" or recommendation, which doesn't fit the site. (I think it applies in this question).

Note: I have nothing against asking a question and then answering, it.  I just don't think the answer should be *part of* the question.

Answer (score 2):

> I just don't think the answer should be part of the question.

Agreed.

I'd prod the user asking the question to answer their own question with an actual answer.

Where to draw the line is the difficult issue.  As you state, it can show that they've done their homework, but at a certain point it becomes like a blog post.  I'd avoid editing it out of their question, at least for a while.